# Not able to search for bluetooth devices in Thinkpad

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, thinkpad

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my thinkpad e440. Neither any of my other android devices able to detect my laptop nor my laptop is able to detect them, with visibility set ON.

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2
```

output is

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:5028]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b728]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Also

```
lsusb
```

output is

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 5986:0397 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also

```
hciconfig -a
```

output is

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
BD Address: 10:08:B1:49:7C:C2  ACL MTU: 820:8  SCO MTU: 255:16
UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
RX bytes:636 acl:0 sco:0 events:41 errors:0
TX bytes:1442 acl:0 sco:0 commands:41 errors:0
Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Name: 'ubuntu-0'
Class: 0x6c0100
Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0xb
LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x8723
Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)
```

Comment: Edit your question to include results from lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lsusb` and `hciconfig -a`

Comment: Results added! @Jeremy31

Comment: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/issues/18 comment from janfromdd gives some steps.  It seems that they are working to get this into a future kernel release